# In C#, is it possible to mock out IMessageReceiver and related classes for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, azureservicebus, sealed-class

I have the following class I wish to create unit tests for:

```
    public class ServiceBusClient {
        private readonly IMessageReceiver messageReceiver;
        private readonly int maximumMessages;

        public ServiceBusClient(IMessageReceiver messageReceiver, int maximumMessages) {
            this.messageReceiver = messageReceiver;
            this.maximumMessages = maximumMessages;
        }

        public async Task<List<EnergyUser>> ReceiveEnergyUsersAsync() {
            List<EnergyUser> energyUsers = new List<EnergyUser>();
            List<string> lockTokens = new List<string>();
            
            this.ReceiveMessages()
                .ForEach((message) => {
                    if (message.Body != null) {
                        energyUsers.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnergyUser>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)));
                    }
                    lockTokens.Add(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                });

            _ = this.messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockTokens);
            return await Task.FromResult(energyUsers);
        }

        private List<Message> ReceiveMessages() {
            return this.messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(this.maximumMessages)
                            .GetAwaiter()
                            .GetResult()
                            .ToList();
        }
    }
```

It will be observed that it is dependent upon `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver`.

My first attempt to mock this out was to use `Moq`. I would have expected if I create a `new Mock<IMessageReceiver>()`, I should be able to inject it into `public ServiceBusClient(IMessageReceiver messageReceiver, int maximumMessages)`, but instead the compiler tells me "Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver>' to 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver"....

Then I thought I would try to manually mock out the class:

```
    internal class MockMessageReceiver : IMessageReceiver {
        public int ReceivedMaxMessgeCount { get; set; }
        public IList<Message> ReturnMessages { get; set; }
        Task<IList<Message>> IMessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(int maxMessageCount) {
            this.ReceivedMaxMessgeCount = maxMessageCount;
            return Task.FromResult(this.ReturnMessages);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> ReceivedLockTokens { get; set; }
        Task IMessageReceiver.CompleteAsync(IEnumerable<string> lockTokens) {
            this.ReceivedLockTokens = lockTokens;
            return Task.Delay(1);
        }

        // Many functions which do nothing just to satisfy the bloated interface.
}
```

This will allow me to successfully provide messages EXCEPT the messages I provide don't include SystemProperties, so ServiceBusClient will throw an error at `lockTokens.Add(message.SystemProperties.LockToken)`.

It turns out that the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message` implementation does not provide a setter for `public SystemPropertiesCollection SystemProperties`, so to set this (unless someone has a better way), I need to create my own implementation of Message:

```
    public class MockMessage : Message {
        public MockMessage(byte[] body) => base.Body = body;

        public new SystemPropertiesCollection SystemProperties {
            get { return this.SystemProperties; }
            set { this.SystemProperties = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now, I can initialize SystemPropertiesCollection, BUT the problem becomes that no property in SystemPropertiesCollection actually includes a setting, so my tests will still fail.

Then I thought: Let's create a mock for "SystemPropertiesCollection" (never mind that we are starting to swim in the dangerous waters of "too much mock".... but when I try to extend this class, my compiler complains because SystemPropertiesCollection is actually a sealed class, so I can't extend it.

So, now I'm back to square one.

Any ideas how I can create good unit tests for ServiceBusClient?

Comment: `var mock = new Mock<IMessageReceiver>();` then you'll be able to setup all required methods, there is no need to implement `IMessageReceiver`

Comment: `Moq` library has a pretty cool [quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, it was partially hidden because I forgot to mark part of the above as code, but that was literally the very first thing I tried.  But even if it succeeded, this would not be enough because I also can't create servicable Messages.

Comment: Which error did you get with `var mock = new Mock<IMessageReceiver>();`? You should inject it like `mock.Object`

Comment: Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Moq.Mock<Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver>' to 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver'

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Jen, no.  In the end, we never created the tests and that project went onto a back burner.

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR

Ran into the same issue and solved it by utilizing reflection to gain access to private members of the class `Message.SystemPropertiesCollection`.

#### More detailed explanation

In order to avoid that `message.SystemProperties.LockToken` throws an `InvalidOperationException` you have to set the `Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.SequenceNumber` property to something else than -1. But the setter of that property is private, the class `Message.SystemPropertiesCollection` is sealed and there is no other indirect way of setting the sequence number without actually sending a message over a service bus. Which you don't want to do in a unit test.

But cheating with reflection to call the private setter of `Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.SequenceNumber` resolved that hurdle and let me fake `Message` objects that don't throw.

#### Sample code

This helper method generates `Message` objects that don't throw.

```cs
private static Message GenerateSaneMessage()
{
    var message = new Message();
    var sysCollectionType = typeof(Message.SystemPropertiesCollection);
    sysCollectionType.GetProperty(nameof(Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.SequenceNumber))!
        .SetValue(message.SystemProperties, 0);
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not ideal solutions I found a few suggestions in currently open GitHub issues.

One was to have a RunInternalAsync method that takes an IReceiverClient messageReceiver that calls the same implementation
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/69

Code suggested in that issue post:

```
// Called by the Service Bus binding.
[FunctionName("Foo")]
public Task RunAsync(
    [ServiceBusTrigger] Message serviceBusMessage,
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver) => RunInternalAsync(serviceBusMessage, messageReceiver);

// Called by unit tests.
internal Task RunInternalAsync(
    Message serviceBusMessage, 
    IReceiverClient messageReceiver { 
    // Implementation
}
```

I ended up going with a property that could be set in the unit test, and then you map that appropriately in your function code.  As documented here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/2218#issuecomment-647584346

Sample code:

```
//Azure Function:
public class ServiceReportingFunction
{
    private ILogger<ServiceReportingFunction> Logger { get; }

    //Needed for unit testing until 'IMessageReceiver messageReceiver' is supported as argument in the Run Method.
    public IMessageReceiver MessageReceiver { get; set; }


    public ServiceReportingFunction(ILogger<ServiceReportingFunction> logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName("ServiceReportingFunction")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceReportingQueueName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
    {
        if (MessageReceiver == null)
            MessageReceiver = messageReceiver;

        ...
    }
}

//Unit (Xunit) test:
public class ServiceReportingFunctionTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async void Test_ServiceReportingFunction()
    {
        var logger = A.Fake<ILogger<ServiceReportingFunction>>();
        var messageReceiver = A.Fake<IMessageReceiver>();

        var function = new ServiceReportingFunction(logger);
        function.MessageReceiver = messageReceiver;
        
        ....

        await function.Run(message, null);

       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `new Mock<IMessageReceiver>()` will return a Mock instance. However, your constructor is expecting IMessageReceiver. That's why the compiler shows an error.

You have to get the instance by calling the `Object` property on the mock like this:

```
var serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
    new Mock<IMessageReceiver>().Object, 
    0
);
```